# Is it possible to tag shapes in draw.io with info similiar to Visio?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'd like to provide more detailed info to shapes in my flow charts on draw.io similar to applying info to shapes in Visio. Is this possible or a possibility in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a shape and on the menu navigate to *Edit* → *Edit Data*. That brings up a dialog that allows you to insert arbitrary key/value pairs of information. That information is displayed when you hover on a shape to see the tooltip.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I was hoping the information assigned to the object would carry over to the html output available but it is not. I would like to embed the charts in a webpage and allow the cursor hover to bring up a note displaying info assigned. I guess I'll try an alternate means.

Comment: That's probably a bug if the embedded version tooltip is different, I'll add an issue.

Comment: Thanks. Its a great product and I'm turning a lot of heads where I work with it's ease of use, flexibility, and visual display.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have assigned the metadata key/value pairs, you can display them on the shapes using %keyname%.